# Merge two column in spark dataframe to form single column

Tags: apache-spark, graph, pyspark

I have a Spark dataframe with two columns; `src_edge` and `dest_edge`. I simply want to create new spark dataframe so that it contains a single column `id` with values from `src_edge` and `dest_edge`.

```
src dst
 1   2
 1   3
```

I want to create `df2` as:

```
id
1
1
2
3
```

If possible, I would also like to create `df2` with no duplicates values. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

```
 id
 1
 2
 3
```

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

The simplest thing may be to select each column, `union` them, and call `distinct`:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df2 = df.select(col("src").alias("id")).union(df.select(col("dst").alias("id"))).distinct()
df2.show()
#+---+
#| id|
#+---+
#|  1|
#|  3|
#|  2|
#+---+
```

---

You can also accomplish this with an outer join:

```python
df2 = df.select(col("src").alias("id"))\
    .join(
        df.select(col("dst").alias("id")),
        on="id",
        how="outer"
    )\
    .distinct()
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a new column using `array` and `explode` to combine and flatten the two columns. Then, to remove duplicates use `dropDuplicates`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, explode

df2 = df.select(explode(array("src", "dst")).alias("id"))
  .dropDuplicates()
```